# Does a linear operator keep equation alive.

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm currently working with the Fourier Transform. So let's say we have some vectors $v$, $w$ and $z$ and their transformed $V$, $W$ and $Z$.

If we know that $v = w+z$, we could also say that $V = W + Z$?

Is that due to linearity of the Fourier Transform and if so, why ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, beacause that's part of what being “linear” means.